# how join multiple cases into the switch statement

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I have a swith where I need to do the same procedure in equal cases. For example:

```
    enum Day
    {
        Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday
    }

    private string Do(Day day)
    {
        switch (day)
        {
            case Day.Monday:
                return "Study";
            case Day.Wednesday:
                return "Study";
            case Day.Friday:
                return "Study";
            case Day.Tuesday:
                return "Play Futbol";
            case Day.Thursday:
                return "Play Futbol";
            default: return "Party";
        }
    }
```

I like join the case statement where I do the same procedure.
I know that a swith is like an if-else statement, but I'll want to know if exist any way to do that with the switch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put the cases together that you want to use the same code.

As Grant noted in the comments, it's in the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx

```
enum Day
{
    Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday
}

private string Do(Day day)
{
    switch (day)
    {
        case Day.Monday:
        case Day.Wednesday:
        case Day.Friday:
            return "Study";
        case Day.Tuesday:
        case Day.Thursday:
            return "Play Futbol";
        default: 
            return "Party";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If on multiple case the same thing should be done you can simply stack these cases:

```
private string Do(Day day)
{
    switch (day)
    {
        case Day.Monday:
        case Day.Wednesday:
        case Day.Friday:
            return "Study";
        case Day.Tuesday:
        case Day.Thursday:
            return "Play Futbol";
        default:
            return "Party";
    }
}
```

If you need to do something in one case and then fall through to another case, this is not directly possible. Instead you have to write an explicitly `goto case`.

```
switch (str)
{
    case "1":
    case "small":
        cost += 25;
        break;
    case "2":
    case "medium":
        cost += 25;
        goto case "1";
    case "3":
    case "large":
        cost += 50;
        goto case "1";
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid selection. Please select 1, 2, or 3.");
        break;
}
```